# Can't access to my app Dokku without www?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dokku

I deployed my app with Ruby on Rails 5.2, dokku 0.12.13, and Lets Encrypt.

I can't access my app via `https://trendmedia.xyz/`, only `https://www.trendmedia.xyz/` works.

```
root@media-ams:~# dokku domains trendmedia.xyz

    !     Deprecated: Please use domains:report
    =====> Global Domain Name
    trendmedia.xyz
    =====> trendmedia.xyz Domain Names
    trendmedia.xyz
    www.trendmedia.xyz
    root@media-ams:~#
```

Comment: @sawa How to open a website without www

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There was a problem with DNS provider